# How to use variable defined in a javascript file in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript file:

```js
var moment = require("moment")

var structuredDate = moment(Date()).format("LLLL")
```

And i wanted to change a `<div>` in html with the date.
I tried this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="bscript.js" async defer></script>
Welcome to my website<br>
Today is: <div id="date"></div>
<script>
    const date = document.getElementById("date")
    date.innerHTML=StructuredDate
</script>
```

But it is not working.
I use Browserify to bundle npm packages.

Comment: Hi. _"It's not working"_ isn't particularly useful. What steps have you taken to debug this code? Do you have any errors in your console? FYI `structuredDate` is not the same as `StructuredDate`.

Comment: @Andy i fixed the structured date typo but it is still not working, and the only errors casted are `Uncaught ReferenceError: structuredDate is not defined`

Comment: Remove `async` and `defer` from your script (that has `src="bscript.js"`).

Comment: @Unmitigated why, and that didn't fix it

Comment: @Unmitigated because i use a template that comes with `async defer` already.

Comment: @Unmitigated still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is working with some changes like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bscript.js" async defer></script>
Welcome to my website<br>
Today is: <div id="date"></div>
<script>
    var structuredDate = moment(Date.now()).format("LLLL");
    const date = document.getElementById("date")
    date.innerHTML=structuredDate
</script>
```

**NOTE: This method is just applied only to client-side**

Comment: Now it gives me no errors but it still doesn't show up

Comment: well, it gives me 1 error saying that `Date.now()` Isn't a function but i fixed it by removing the parenthesis

Comment: I think the problem is you called `moment` to fill the value in `structuredDate` on the server-side (In this case node js as about `app.js` / `index.js`). But the code above runs only on HTML

Comment: if you read the whole text the you would know that i use browserify to turn npm packages into clientside scripts

Answer (score 0):

Main thing is that you have used the capital 'S' for the variable inside the  tag js content. change that to
`date.innerHTML = structureDate`

And after that, you will see that undefined in the place where you need to see your date. Just copy and paste the following to set the date in that js file.

`let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString()`

`var structuredDate = today`

This will provide you with the following output. I think that is your required output too.

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SauCl.png)

Comment: No, i wanted to structure it using the moment npm package, and i fixed the typo and it is still giving me `Uncaught ReferenceError: structuredDate is not defined` error

Answer (score -1):

It should `structuredDate` not `StructuredDate`.

date.innerHTML = structuredDate;

Comment: Well, still doesn't work